# SCTP - Data Bursts when Streaming

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-programming, sctp

I'm currently working on an SCTP server which will be used to control a robot over network. In one of the usage scenarios, a stream of desired positions of the robot is sent to the server.

However, when sending this stream I am having the problem that the data does not arrive continuously (it is sent to the server with 100Hz) , but in bursts. This means that the data does not arrive in steps of 10 milliseconds at the server but that there is one big delay of 200 milliseconds after which then 19 messages follow with basically no time delay. So in the mean this makes again a 10 milliseconds delay between to messages.

What I already found out that it probably has to do with some internal buffers. This is because when not only the client sends to the server but also the server sends to the client (in my tests also with 100 Hz), then all data arrives continuously. However, when the client does not collect the data which the server sends to him, then the data flow is only smooth at the beginning and changes to the described bursts after some time. This change seems to occur when the sending buffer of the server is full and hence the SCTP send method blocks.

I could reproduce this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 12.04 (I did not check any other distributions).

I already uploaded a testbench for this problem (a CMake project) to DropCanvas - the link is: http://dropcanvas.com/0ztrt

After building the project, you can run the

```
test_server
```

executable. This executable starts an SCTP server and exchanges some messages between the server and a client. It measures the time between the message arrival at the server and stores the measurements in a file

```
time_log.txt
```

If you pass no arguments, then only the client sends to the server, If you call the program with

```
./test_server 1 0
```

then the server will also stream to the client, but the client will no read the data. If you call it with

```
./test_server 1 1
```

the server will send to the client and the client will also read the data.

If someone could help me out here that would be great.
Regards,
Pascal

Comment: Pascal, I doubt anyone will take the time to download, compile and test your whole code. Please make your question more specific. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you try setting the socket option that disables Nagel's algorithm?

Comment: Bullseye! That was exactly the problem! Thanks for pointing this out